# Getting error : Database location or iosDatabaseLocation value is now mandatory in openDatabase call

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am using android-cordova-ionic with ngCordova sqlite.

I am getting error Database location or iosDatabaseLocation value is now mandatory in openDatabase call on device.

I have run example https://github.com/teerasej/Ionic-Example-SQLite which is working fine but when i moving code to my app it give above error.

```
 try {
  db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name:"nextflow.db",location:'default'});
} catch (error) {
  alert(error);
}
```

Is there any configuration mistake?